# jQueryMobile: Wrap all words matching a condition with a span?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile page with text under the element (simple page):

```
<div data-role='content' >
```

Using jQuery how can I wrap each occurrence of the word `Canada` with a span like this:

```
<span class='query'>Canada</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div[data-role="content"]').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/(Canada)/gi, '<span class="query">$1</span>');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9CXFR/

Comment: +1 to this indeed! not sure about `i` - /i makes the regex match case insensitive. only for OP though, cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit - I figured the OP will also want to match `canada`. If not, just remove the `i`.

Comment: Tats_innit: I love your demo text in jsfiddle. It is the best country in the world. Public schools have iPads...

Comment: Aha Joseph cool yep got it `:)` thank-you, @BahaiResearch.com `:P` ha ha

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QeZxn/7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/QeZxn/6/

g = /g modifier makes sure that all occurrences of "replacement"

good read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo = $('div[data-role="content"]');

    $foo.html($foo.text().replace(/Canada/g,'<span class="query">Canada</span>'));

});
```